# Laptop won't boot after failed hibernation and power cycle

Tags: boot-failure, hibernate

I have Ubuntu 12.04 by installed on my Inspiron N5030. Its my only operating system. Recently, ubuntu had a problem with resuming from hibernation. This has happened before, and I simply held the power button until the system shut down and restarted without a problem. Now I did the same thing once again, except this time, my system wont boot. Could I have damaged ubuntu by shutting my computer off manually? Is there anything I can do to fix it? I'd really rather not lose all my data.

Comment: try this: Unplug the laptop, and take the battery out for about 30 secs... plug everything back in, and press the power button...

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Can you boot from an Ubuntu live CD/USB? If you can, you may be able to copy your data to an external drive.

Answer (score 1):

As Joshua commented, try to take out your battery and unplug it from the power supply. Then press the power button and hold it for 20-30 seconds.

It should not have anything to do with your os if you get no error messages.

Comment: this actually happens to my laptop a lot. And disconnecting all power sources and holding the powerbutton down always works for me

Comment: Can work wonders on phones as well.